# Database Schema for Complex Menu Filter with Dynamic Item Count

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I am new here and it seems like a great place to get some advice. I have zero experience with back-end programming, but I am hoping to understand it better now that I want to compile a simple fool-proof database that could end up growing to millions of records if other people are as interested in macroscale concepts as I am. The focus is not on the records - which will contain only a few text strings of unique data - but on dynamic categorization. I would like to create is a page with up to 300 multi-level sortable categories with item counts. When a user clicks a category, all the records are re-calculated and new item count is displayed for all the categories. A user can continue filtering through the categories or click on any of the item counts to generate a list of matching records.

You can view a basic outline of my vague idea here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huoPI.jpg

So if you were me, how would you structure the database schema to make the simultaneous filtration and count process resource-friendly? Records would be added and updated on daily basis, but it wouldn't be a tremendous load and none of the information is time sensitive. I am used to working with front-end design, so it all makes sense in a visual context, but I have no idea whether it's better to create one table with a 100 columns or to use some kind of normalization and indexing.

Comment: Before you take another breath... see normalization!

Comment: Ok, I understand that I need to create a separate table for every record that is not unique in the row, but I am not clear on what's the optimal way to join records and categories. What if 1 record applies to 50 categories, is there a better way to organize it (like by some kind of indexing or grouping) instead of duplicating the item-pid 50 times with 50 different category-pids in a relational table? Also, does it make any difference if the first column is item-pid and not category-pid when most of the activity is relating to categories counting records? Thank you.

Comment: As a general rule, get the thing normalized first (to 3NF), and worry about performance after.